# Gnuplot format palette legend as time

Tags: gnuplot

I have a plot that has the zaxis as the time and a palette whose colors correspond to those same time values. The rendering seems fine but, my zaxis legend shows the time properly formatted and the palette legend only shows some numbers (I assume those numbers are the same time but in seconds).

[image: plot with wrong format in palette]

Is there a way to make the palette use the same legend format as the zaxis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the format for the color palette separately:

```
set cbdata time
set format cb "%H:%M:%S"
```